# importing base from deap library

Tags: radix, python-3.10, deap

i am using python 3.10, pip 22.1.1, setuptools 58.0.0 and deap 1.3.1
when i am imporing base from deap it shoed error and could not fix it.
[error message while importing base][1]

```html
import deap
from deap import base
```

importing creator and tools worked but base has not been imported.
help me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWhBY.png

Comment: Please avoid attaching error messages as images. [Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) recommend that you include error messages as text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Deap is using Python2 syntax here so Python 3.10 doesn't support it and so there is a syntax error. Before setuptool 58, it uses a builtin tool called 2to3 to automatically convert such Python 2 syntax to corresponding Python 3 one but 2to3 tool is just a temporary solution that helps Python 2 to Python 3 transition more smoothly and since Python 2 is already EOL the 2to3 tool is also dropped since setuptool 58. Without conversion Python 3.10 won't load Python 2 code. Deap developers are aware of the issue and solving it (see [this issue](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/pull/625)). For now, you can downgrade setuptool version to 57 using `pip install --upgrade setuptools==57.5` and wait deap to fix the issue.